# Can someone explain what "Standby time" is on iOS?

Tags: iphone

Here's my iOS 6.0.1 log after about 9 hours off the charger. "Standby" seems to be including "Usage".

I've had the phone off the wall for only 9 hrs, but the sum of Standby and Usage are over 15 hrs.

What is "Standby time" on iOS 6 anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All iOS use the same definitions of standby time.

**Standby** is the accumulation of all of all powered on time since its lasts full charge. Whether the device is actively being used, running with the screen off or sleeping, this time counts towards the standby category.

**Usage** is the amount of time the iPhone has been awake and in use since the last full charge. This use can be an active use or **certain background tasks** like navigation or checking mail periodically or receiving push notifications and events.

The only time between now and the last time of charge that doesn't go towards standby is if you power down the device.

Therefore, if you've got some background tasks, such us auto-cheking emails, or any background-running Apps, the numbers for the **Usage Time** will increase although you're not actively using your phone.

Comment: It would seem if I'm using the phone, it's not on standby. That's a misnomer...

Comment: @ERJ Yes, it was puzzling me to. See my thinking in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/46741/23504). It should be named "total time" or similar.